# Dispatch Async in iOS doesn't send Block to Background thread

Tags: ios, background-process, dispatch-async

Block of Code has to be run on the Background Thread. So structure of the App is:

PARENT CLASS (ABSTRACT METHOD)
CHILD CLASS (ABSTRACT METHOD IMPLEMENTATION)

CHILD CLASS:
Method Call has been surrounded by:

```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {}
```

PROBLEM:
Still it runs on the Main Thread. if i put Sleep(20) it block the Main UI for 20 sec.
Block of Code is DB insertions & Web Call.

Please suggest what can be the Problem.

Comment: Hi. Trying to help but need more context. Can you provide some more code please?

Comment: Are you sure it runs on the main thread?  Rather than sleeping add the following within the block: `NSLog(@"Main thread? %@", [NSThread isMainThread] ? @"Yes" : @"No");`.